# findViewById in Service

Tags: android, service, findviewbyid

I have a service which "start service" can be called through 2 activities, and I want to change an image view while service starts, but when I'm trying to "findViewById"
I got this error.

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Main
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the `ImageView` from the activity, not the service.

Comment: Because I've 2 activities I rather to change 'imageView' from service. is there any solution?

Comment: @Reza_Rg: You cannot update your UI from a `Service`. Please update your UI from your activities.

Answer (score 0):

you should distinguish `findviewByid(int)` and `Layout.inflate(int)`,so my suggestion is :

- obtain the parent view in Activity with `Layout.inflate(int)`
- use parent view to call `findViewById(int)`

have a try,happy code :)

Comment: How to option parent view in Activity? can you be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by passing the context to the service and doing:

```
mContext.findViewById(int)
```

But it would be more logical if you call to an activity's function via intents, static methods or aidl (I suggest intents or static), let's say "changeImage()" and let the activity do all the view-handling work